# Get two records from PLSQL cursor

Tags: plsql

My question is short. I create a cursor to get some values from my table. I want to get the current record of cursor (the fetched record) and the next record from the cursor without fetching it, because I want to make a calculation over the current record and the next record.  In traditional programming it's a simple operation; you can do it with a for index by increasing it by 1.

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Is this PostgreSQL's PL/SQL or Oracle's PLSQL?

Answer (score 6):

> I want to make a calculation over the
>   current record and the next record.

Presuming you are using Oracle, this can be done quite simply in SQL using analtyical functions, specifically the `lead()` function.  This retrieves a column's value from the next nth record (default n=1).

```
SQL> select empno
  2         , sal as this_sal
  3         , lead(sal) over (order by empno) as next_sal
  4  from emp
  5  order by empno
  6  /

     EMPNO   THIS_SAL   NEXT_SAL
---------- ---------- ----------
      7369        800       1600
      7499       1600       1250
      7521       1250       2975
      7566       2975       1250
      7654       1250       2850
      7698       2850       2450
....
```

This query can be using in a cursor or any other mechanism for retrieving records.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you can do that without moving the cursor, but you should be able to accomplish the same goal like this (psuedocode):

```
open cursor;
fetch cursor to rec1;
if cursor%found then
   loop      
      fetch cursor to rec2;
      exit when cursor%notfound;
      perform calculations with rec1 and rec2;
      rec1 := rec2;
   end loop;
end if;
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer you specific question, you could use BULK COLLECT and its limit clause into a collection (table) variable.

```
DECLARE
  CURSOR my_cursor IS
    [YOUR SQL HERE];

  TYPE t_my_type IS TABLE OF my_cursor%ROWTYPE INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
  v_my_var   t_my_type;
BEGIN
  FETCH my_cursor BULK COLLECT INTO v_my_var LIMIT 2;
  dbms_output.put_line('My first value: ' || v_my_var(1).some_column);
  dbms_output.put_line('My second value: ' || v_my_var(2).some_column);
END;
```

The limit clause will cause only the first two records to be fetched and stored. The first record will have an index of 1 and the second will be 2.

Answer (score 0):

You can compare two variables by saving one into local and then compare it with cursor value for example

```
declare
l_local1 table_name%type := null;

begin

for c1 in (select 
             * 
           from 
             table_name 
           where some clause)
loop
-- do comparation
  if l_local1 is not null and c1.field_value is not null then
    -- do something to compare
     .
     .
     .
    -- empty local1 variable
    l_local1 := null;
  end if; 
  -- get the value of loop in local variable
  l_local1 := c1.field_value;
end loop;

end;
```